# Error when runnint jmeter distributed load testing

Tags: java, server, jmeter, rmi

I am performing jmeter distributed load testing, On starting remote server from local machine in gui mode test starts but not able to start on local machine. It gives rmi UnmarshalException on local machine. The detail error is that

```
2020-08-15 15:09:51,364 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 5.1.1 r1855137
2020-08-15 15:09:51,364 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_131
2020-08-15 15:09:51,364 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
2020-08-15 15:09:51,364 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Mac OS X
2020-08-15 15:09:51,364 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=x86_64
2020-08-15 15:09:51,364 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=10.15.4
2020-08-15 15:09:51,364 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
2020-08-15 15:09:51,364 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.awt.headless=true
2020-08-15 15:09:51,364 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =1908932608
2020-08-15 15:09:51,365 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =4
2020-08-15 15:09:51,895 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 1.2.3.4:8113
2020-08-15 15:09:51,898 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-15 15:09:52,055 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting remote engines
2020-08-15 15:09:52,056 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting the test @ Sat Aug 15 15:09:52 CST 2020 (1597475392055)
2020-08-15 15:09:52,056 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method
2020-08-15 15:09:52,063 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2020-08-15 15:09:52,063 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2020-08-15 15:09:52,541 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-15 15:09:52,546 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-08-15 15:09:52,559 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-15 15:09:52,559 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-15 15:09:52,561 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-15 15:09:53,108 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-15 15:09:53,108 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-15 15:09:53,108 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-15 15:09:53,109 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-15 15:09:53,109 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-15 15:10:53,356 ERROR o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:229) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.rconfigure(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.runTest(ClientJMeterEngine.java:153) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.start(DistributedRunner.java:132) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.start(DistributedRunner.java:149) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:1089) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:991) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:563) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:253) [ApacheJMeter.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:215) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    ... 15 more
2020-08-15 15:10:53,378 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Interrupting RMI Reaper
2020-08-15 15:10:53,380 ERROR o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
2020-08-15 15:10:53,381 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started
```

anyone know the reason?

Comment: Was the connection killed prematurely?

Comment: @JCWasmx86 I did not do anything during the running.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the relevant pkg's to your java.security file, something like ->

> sun.rmi.registry.registryFilter=java.**;org.apache.**

**EDIT**

in java-11 the file is under $JAVA_HOME/jdk/conf/security/

in java-8 the file is under $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/

Comment: could you tell me where to add it in for Jmeter?